# How do I change the color of the title bar of a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, titlebar

I want to change the skin of the title bar so that it would be the same to that of the UITabBar which is black. How can I achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor
```

Comment: The line returns a build error: Request for member 'tintColor' in something not a structure or union.